# Can we pray after sex if we didn't ejaculate?

Tags: sharia, sex, ghusl

Is it permissible to pray Salah if we have had sex but did not ejaculate? I am totally aware that we must shower in order to pray simply if we ejaculate.

Comment: I read in a book that Ghusal becomes obligatory if the penis enters the vagina to an extent that the head of the penis also knowns as glans penis gets covered by the vagina.

Answer (score 15):

According to majority of scholars, If the male organ enters woman even once, then Ghusl is obligatory on both. Ejaculation is not the condition for Ghusl, entering into woman is.

Also, If ejaculation happens without penetration, even then ghusl is fard. So in both cases ghusl is fard. So, you must do ghusl before praying, otherwise prayer will not be valid.

> If there was no actual penetrative intercourse, and no ejaculation /
> orgasm, then ghusl (bath) is not required. If only one of the couple
> experienced orgasm / ejaculation, then that individual is required to
> perform ghusl. If there was penetrative intercourse, then both man and
> woman must perform ghusl, even if there was no ejaculation nor orgasm.
>
> Reference: [Qibla.com](http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=12&ID=12832&CATE=10)

Comment: Can you please provide reference with your comments

Comment: Updated the answer with reference, if you need more details, please go here: http://islamqa.com/en/5560

Answer (score 4):

**No**, it is mandatory to perform ghusl-e-janabat after intercourse even if you have not ejaculated. If water is not available or harmful for you , you must do tayammum.

*[Note: The answer is from a shia perspective.]*

Comment: Sunni view is the same

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not permissible to pray after having sex even without ejaculating, unless you perform ghusl al-janabah. The Prophet (PBUH) said (this hadith in Sunan Ibn Majah)

> “When the two circumcised parts meet and the tip of the penis
>   disappears, then ghusl becomes obligatory.”

And in Sahih Muslim:

> “When a man sits between the four parts (arms and legs of his wife)
>   and the one circumcised part touches the other, then ghusl is
>   obligatory.”

---

[Source](https://islamqa.info/en/170796)

Answer (score 0):

Whether ejaculation has occurred or not, ghusl/shower is a must for prayer. Because we should try that our prayer should be offered in a clean state.

So ghusl is must in all such cases.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. This site is about Islam and answer should, in most cases, be backed up by reference. Questions and answers here are supposed to be academic in nature and quality is key. Please go through the [help], [answer], and also [meta] if you happen to have any queries, suggestions or even better want to know more and participate in the building of this site.

Comment: @hus787 ok sure and thanks for the informatiom