# Is it permissable to pray after intercourse?

Tags: sex, taharah, ghusl

Is it necessary to take full bath or shower after engaging in intercourse (or even a love bite and a smooch)?

Comment: You'd better search before asking such a question. The answer is available most of the sites!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we pray after sex if we didn't ejaculate?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/can-we-pray-after-sex-if-we-didnt-ejaculate)

Answer (score 7):

walikum salam

No it's not allowed to pray right after intercourse unless you first took a bath.

Sex brings upon a state of being in ceremonial impurity and requires ghusl [Surah al-Maidah 5:6]

Once you have taken a bath, only then can you pray.

Comment: any reference please

Comment: @Hussain Surah al-Maidah ayah 6

Comment: Yeah, as @Sayyid mentioned correctly, "Sex brings upon a state of being in ceremonial impurity and requires ghusl [Surah al-Maidah 5:6]"

Answer (score 0):

After intercourse it's good to have a bath if possible, if not only the washing can do too.
If you had intercourse I presume you're at home so it's possible to have a bath.

After a kiss or love bite the bath is not obligatory, not even the washing.

Allah loves those who clean themselves a lot so it doesn't matter what you did, before praying I think washing is the best way to start any prayer or any Quran reading.